Looking for Belgian short silent movie about dystopian society
I'm looking for a Belgian short silent movie, black & white, probably from the 30s. I saw the movie some 30 years ago, when our physics teacher showed it to us, probably because class finished 10 minutes too early. It's about a dystopian society in which people are forced to walk near the walls. After a while some try to go to the middle of the street, after which they are shot. It's not clear by whom and why they are shot, but after the incident people move away from the middle of the street and continue to shuffle along the walls.

Is there any chance you could reach out to your teacher? Not saying we can't figure it out but shorts can be difficult.

Found it, asked somebody from the local cinema. Turns out it is "De Overkant" from Herman Wuyts. The movie is from 1966 (doh!). The English title is "The Other Side", so contratry to what I thought people are trying to cross the street, not just merely go away from the side.
In 2015 the film was shown at the kortfilmfestival where he was pitched like so:


Men and women, face pressed against the wall, go sideways, step by step. They can not possibly cross the street.

